# icloudkit dashboard verify records in private database custom zone

Tags: database, private, dashboard, cloudkit, ckrecord

Can we check the record entry in private database in iCloudkit dashboard in development environment? Apple does mentions in its getting started guide as "1. In the left column of CloudKit Dashboard, click Default Zone under Public Data or Private Data.
Records appear in the second column. (If you don’t use a custom zone, records are stored in the public default zone.)"

So if anyone know then how can i verify the records once in development environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you successfully stored records in a custom zone of the private database for your user, then you will see the name of that zone appear under the "Private Database" header in the left sidebar. To be clear, the user you're logging into the Dashboard with needs to be the same user logged into iCloud on your device or simulator. You're not allowed to see the private data for other users.

Here is a screenshot from my Dashboard, showing records in a private database custom zone named "Todos."

[image: CloudKit Dashboard]

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can make this private data visible in iCloud Drive? (sorry, I know this is a bit late)

Comment: @amergin CloudKit is a lower-level API for storing any type of data and having more control, and there are separate APIs if you want to store documents in iCloud Drive: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForDocumentsIniCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH2-SW1